Wilcoxon Test using geom-signif, how to specify paired or unpaired?
Here is my current code: Can you show me how to specify a paired and unpaired using geom_signif?
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(Treatment_Box, aes(x = Treatment,
                          y = Dv50,
                          )) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Days_Mixing), width = .1, size = 2) +
  ylim(15,32) +
  theme_bw() +
  
  labs(title = "90-day Treatment Size Comparison (Dv50)",
        y = "Particle Size (microns)") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  
  geom_signif(
    comparisons = list(c("T2", "T4")), 
    test = "wilcox.test", step_increase = 0.075, 
    map_signif_level = TRUE, annotations = "NS", tip_length = .03)


Presumably with the test.args argument, maybe test.args = list(paired = TRUE). But I can't try it out since I cannot run your code.

I was right: https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/issues/36
